# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in React + Phoenix framework

Tags: json, reactjs, postgresql, axios, material-ui

I'm new to React. I have provided **Postgresql API** and I want to add those data in **Material UI Table**.
I've made some mistakes and I'm unable to figure to out.
I'm using API calls for the first time using **Axios**. So please guide me to solve this issue.

I'm using **React.js** for frontend work, **Phoenix framework** for backend, and **PostgreSQL database**.

The below component is used to handle API request using Axios

```
import axios from "axios"
import MedicineCard from './MedicineCard'

class Medicines extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { medicines: [] };
      }
    componentWillMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:4000/medicines')
          .then(response => {
            this.setState({ medicines: response.data.medicines });
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      }
      
      render() {
        const posts = this.state.medicines.map((medicine, index) =>
          <MedicineCard
            key = { index }
            medid = {medicine.medid}
            medname = {medicine.medname}
          />
        )
        return (
          <div>
          {posts}
          </div>
        )
      }
  }

  export default Medicines
```

Below Component is used for Material UI Table

```
import React from 'react'
import MaterialTable from 'material-table'

class MedicineCard extends React.Component{
    render(){
    const data=[
        {medid:this.props.medid,medname:this.props.medname}
    ]
    const column=[
        {
            title:'Medicine_ID',field:'medid'
        },
        {
            title:'Medicine_Name',field:'medname'
        }
    ]
    return (
    <div>
    <MaterialTable title="Material Table" 

        data={data}
        column ={column}
    />
    </div>
  
    );
}
}

export default MedicineCard
```

This component is used to display UI

```
import React from 'react'
import Medicines from './Medicines'

const Test = () => (
  <div>
  <Medicines />
      
  </div>
)
export default Test
```

Please help me and guide me out to solve this issue

Comment: it looks like your `response.data` doesn't have the property `medicines`. that will update your state `medicines` to `undefined`, triggering the error. you should try to `console.log(response.data)` to check it

Comment: componentWillMount is considered legacy, call the APIs in componentDidMount.

Comment: I tried console.log(response.data) and it displays my JSON API values in the console. I want those values to be displayed in Material UI Table

Comment: based on your comments, you probably need to setState like this `this.setState({ medicines: response.data});`